# Right way to secure a web server through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi i'm new in web programming. I'm developing a web site with a PHP backend application. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 Server, Apache, PHP 5.5 and Mysql. 
Currently this is my directory structure under /var/www/html:

```
example.com
    app/  # this dir contains the backend
    src/  # this contains some common stuffs between front and back ends
    web/  # this is the 'public directory' which serves the frontend
```

I searched so much about .htaccess, but i cant point out a definitive solution to secure all .php files which are not into the `web/` directory. Also, i would "hide" .php files through url rewriting (for example, instead of serve `mysite.org/accounts.php` i would serve `mysite.org/accounts`, but not just removing the .php extensions, rather redirecting `mysite.org/accounts` to a file called, to say, `youwillneverknowthis.php`).

Thanks in advance.

J.

Answer (score -2):

1. To protect your PHP files, do not put them in the public `html` directory because it's accessible via the internet.  Files that contain private code should be taken out of that directory. Put them in private directories such as `/var/www/php/src` and `var/www/php/app`
2. Now you want users to be able to get "page.php" without exposing the sensitive PHP code.  One solution is to have a script in the public directory `/var/www/html` called `gateway.php` that looks in the private directory `dir` for a file named `file` and execute its contents. The values of $_GET come from step 4 below.  Before requiring the file, be sure to sanitize input to prevent a malicious actor from making `gateway.php` run a bad script.  For instance, you can compare the requested file against a whitelist of allowed files and stop execution if there is no match.

   ```
   <?php #gateway.php
   if (empty($_GET['file'])):
       //the file is missing
       http_response_code(400); //bad request
       exit;
   else:
       $file = realpath(rawurlencode("/var/www/php/$_GET[dir]/$_GET[file]"));

       //SAFE_SCRIPTS is a string constant: whitelist of allowed files
       //eg:define("SAFE_SCRIPTS",'"path/to/a.php","path/to/b.php"')
       if(strpos(SAFE_SCRIPTS,$file)===false):
           //script is not in the whitelist
           http_response_code(403);//Forbidden
           trigger_error("Forbidden script: $file");
           die("Access to this resource is forbidden");
       endif;
       require $file;
   endif;
   ```
3. Your next issue was about url rewriting so that `mysite.org/accounts` could redirect to `youwillneverknowthis.php`). Place a text file named `.htaccess` in the public document root `var/www/html`. Add the following rule (one rule per line): `RewriteEngine on`. This turns on url rewriting
4. To redirect a url, add the following rule (single line): `RewriteRule ^accounts$ gateway.php?dir=src&file=youwillneverknowthis.php [QSA,L]` Adjust the dir and file arguments as required.  This will redirect the user to gateway.php, which will then read and execute the private code, all behind the scenes.  The Query String Append [[QSA]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag ensures that any pre-existing query arguments are passed to `gateway.php` along with `dir` and `file` arguments. The [[L]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag lets the rewriting engine know to stop processing and redirect upon finding a match.

Hope that helps.

Edit: improve security by sanitizing input

Comment: Regarding #2, using that method without sanitizing the input will let a user include any arbitrary file that the webserver has read access to. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability It would be better to build your application with a single entry point and not worry about which requests route to which files.

Comment: I do not agree with lots of stuff here. One of them is `Place a text file named .htaccess (no name, just extension)` .htaccess is not a file with extension but not name, it's just a hidden file (with no extension, actually). Also @mtinsley pointed out some serious security issues..

Comment: Thank you guys for your great feedback!  I've adjusted my solution; please let me know what you think.